# getServerSideProps is undefined in nextjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

I want to pass an array(initialPosts) using getServerSideProps into my Home function . But the props are undefined. I have looked through many solutions but none of them works.

I have used initialPosts as props in getserversideprops , in it the array data is present.
I have used posts to store initialPosts props in Home function and a map function named posts.map().

Error is on the line post.map() in Home function.

Error:
"TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')"

```
import Header from '../component/header'
import { useState } from 'react'


export async function getServerSideProps(context){
    return{
        props:{
            initialPosts: [
              {
                  user: "Dilpreet",
                  profile: 'img/dilpreet.jpg',
                  url: 'img/meme.jpg',
                  caption: "New meme i found #thor",
                  comment_user: "Manik",
                  comment: "my dentist to me :))",
              },
              {
                  user: "Manik",
                  profile: 'img/dilpreet.jpg',
                  url: 'img/meme2.jpg',
                  caption: "New meme i found #alien",
                  comment_user: "Manik",
                  comment: "my dentist to me :))",
              },
              {
                  user: "Dilpreet",
                  profile: 'img/dilpreet.jpg',
                  url: 'img/meme3.jpg',
                  caption: "New meme i found #himanshu",
                  comment_user: "Manik",
                  comment: "my dentist to me :))",
              }
          ],
        },
    }
}


function Home(props){
    const [posts,setPosts] = useState(props.initialPosts)

    return(
        <div className='m-3'>
            {/* Header */}

                <Header />

            {/* Main */}
      
            <section className='flex flex-row'>
                <div className='w-1/2 h-screen'></div>
                <div className='w-1/2 bg-emerald-300 flex flex-row'>

                    {/* <Feed posts={initialPosts} /> */}
                    <div className="flex flex-col overflow-auto scroll-smooth no-scrollbar h-screen w-full rounded-xl">
            {
                posts.map((n) => {
                    return(
                        <>
                        <div className="flex flex-row mx-auto">
    
                        {/* User post */}
              
                        <div className='flex flex-col mb-16 rounded-xl bg-slate-100 shadow-xl shadow-bg-slate-300'>
              
                          {/* User post content */}
              
                          <div className='flex flex-col'>
              
                            {/* User profile */}
                            <div className='flex flex-row items-center mx-4 mt-3'>
              
                              {/* Profile pic of user */}
              
                              <div className='relative inline-block'>
                                <img class="inline-block object-cover w-12 h-12 rounded-full" src={n.profile}></img>
                                <span class="absolute bottom-0 right-0 inline-block w-3 h-3 bg-green-600 border-2 border-white rounded-full"></span>
                              </div>
              
                              {/* UserName */}
              
                              <h1 className="mx-2">{n.user}</h1>
              
                              {/* Status */}
              
                              <div></div>
              
                            </div>
              
                            {/* Post */}
              
                            <div className='mx-auto'>
                              <img className="h-[768px] w-[768px] object-contain" src={n.url}></img>
                            </div>
                          </div>
              
                          {/* User post caption */}
              
                          <div className="my-5 mx-3">
                            {n.caption}
                          </div>
    
                          {/* Buttons */}
    
                          <div className="flex flex-row p-4">
                            <button className="w-1/3">Like</button>
                            <button className="w-1/3">Comment</button>
                            <button className="w-1/3">Send</button>
                          </div>
                        </div>
    
                    </div> 
                    </>                 
                    )
                    })
            }
            </div>
          
                </div>
            </section>
      
            </div>
    )
}

export default Home
```

My _app.js file:

```
import '../styles/globals.css'

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return <Component {...pageProps} />
}

export default MyApp
```

Comment: Are you calling getServerSideProps in the pages folder? because getServerSideProps only works inside the Pages folder components

Comment: yes its inside the pages folder

Comment: 1. You don't need useState in this case
2. You have to add unique "key" to every element when you generate them via "posts.map"
3. With React you have to use "className" instead of "class"
4. It would be better to use next/image component instead of html <img />
5. If using relative image it must start with a leading slash "/" or be an absolute URL (http:// or https://)

Other than that your code works great. You could check https://codesandbox.io/s/throbbing-dawn-5dkqow?file=/pages/index.js

Comment: I have used the solution you provide here https://codesandbox.io/s/throbbing-dawn-5dkqow?file=/pages/index.js , still getting the same error on my machine. Screenshot:- https://i.imgur.com/BUl5fKp.png

Comment: So maybe the problem is not in that piece of code

Comment: I don't think there's anything wrong with your code, you even verified it works on codesandbox. Try deleting the `.next` folder in your project and rerun the development server again.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The code below is tested & working.

If you `CTRL+C` & `CTRL+V` this code and it doesn't work it means you have errors in settings/params

```
import * as React from "react";
import { useState } from "react";


export default function Home(props){
  const [posts,setPosts] = useState(props.initialPosts)
  //all is good, data is passing to your Home component
  console.log(posts)
  return(
      <div className='m-3'>


          {/* Main */}
    
          <section className='flex flex-row'>
              <div className='w-1/2 h-screen'></div>
              <div className='w-1/2 bg-emerald-300 flex flex-row'>

                  {/* <Feed posts={initialPosts} /> */}
                  <div className="flex flex-col overflow-auto scroll-smooth no-scrollbar h-screen w-full rounded-xl">
          {
              posts.map((n) => {
                  return(
                      <>
                      <div className="flex flex-row mx-auto">
  
                      {/* User post */}
            
                      <div className='flex flex-col mb-16 rounded-xl bg-slate-100 shadow-xl shadow-bg-slate-300'>
            
                        {/* User post content */}
            
                        <div className='flex flex-col'>
            
                          {/* User profile */}
                          <div className='flex flex-row items-center mx-4 mt-3'>
            
                            {/* Profile pic of user */}
            
                            <div className='relative inline-block'>
                              <img className="inline-block object-cover w-12 h-12 rounded-full" src={n.profile} />
                              <span className="absolute bottom-0 right-0 inline-block w-3 h-3 bg-green-600 border-2 border-white rounded-full"></span>
                            </div>
            
                            {/* UserName */}
            
                            <h1 className="mx-2">{n.user}</h1>
            
                            {/* Status */}
            
                            <div></div>
            
                          </div>
            
                          {/* Post */}
            
                          <div className='mx-auto'>
                            <img className="h-[768px] w-[768px] object-contain" src={n.url}></img>
                          </div>
                        </div>
            
                        {/* User post caption */}
            
                        <div className="my-5 mx-3">
                          {n.caption}
                        </div>
  
                        {/* Buttons */}
  
                        <div className="flex flex-row p-4">
                          <button className="w-1/3">Like</button>
                          <button className="w-1/3">Comment</button>
                          <button className="w-1/3">Send</button>
                        </div>
                      </div>
  
                  </div> 
                  </>                 
                  )
                  })
          }
          </div>
        
              </div>
          </section>
    
          </div>
  )
}

export async function getServerSideProps(context){
  return{
      props:{
          initialPosts: [
            {
                user: "Dilpreet",
                profile: 'img/dilpreet.jpg',
                url: 'img/meme.jpg',
                caption: "New meme i found #thor",
                comment_user: "Manik",
                comment: "my dentist to me :))",
            },
            {
                user: "Manik",
                profile: 'img/dilpreet.jpg',
                url: 'img/meme2.jpg',
                caption: "New meme i found #alien",
                comment_user: "Manik",
                comment: "my dentist to me :))",
            },
            {
                user: "Dilpreet",
                profile: 'img/dilpreet.jpg',
                url: 'img/meme3.jpg',
                caption: "New meme i found #himanshu",
                comment_user: "Manik",
                comment: "my dentist to me :))",
            }
        ],
      },
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes it should work but it kills all the purpose of ServerSideRendering. You are holding all data in the React State which needs JS to run on browser.